# Error in the push Heroku, json and ruby ​​1.9.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, heroku, git-push

I have a problem at the time of the push Heroku, follow the below error

```
-----> Gemfile detected, running Bundler version 1.0.7
   Unresolved dependencies detected; Installing...
   Using --without development:test
   Fetching source index for http://rubygems.org/
   Installing rake (0.9.2) 
   Installing abstract (1.0.0) 
   Installing activesupport (3.0.9) 
   Installing builder (2.1.2) 
   Installing i18n (0.5.0) 
   Installing activemodel (3.0.9) 
   Installing erubis (2.6.6) 
   Installing rack (1.2.3) 
   Installing rack-mount (0.6.14) 
   Installing rack-test (0.5.7) 
   Installing tzinfo (0.3.29) 
   Installing actionpack (3.0.9) 
   Installing mime-types (1.16) 
   Installing polyglot (0.3.2) 
   Installing treetop (1.4.10) 
   Installing mail (2.2.19) 
   Installing actionmailer (3.0.9) 
   Installing arel (2.0.10) 
   Installing activerecord (3.0.9) 
   Installing activeresource (3.0.9) 
   Installing diff-lcs (1.1.2) 
   Installing json (1.5.3) with native extensions 
   /usr/ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/specification.rb:519:in `normalize_yaml_input': invalid byte sequence in US-ASCII (ArgumentError)
    from /usr/ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/specification.rb:479:in `from_yaml'
    from /usr/ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/package/tar_input.rb:183:in `load_gemspec'
    from /usr/ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/package/tar_input.rb:51:in `block in initialize'
    from /usr/ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/package/tar_reader.rb:64:in `block in each'
    from /usr/ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/package/tar_reader.rb:55:in `loop'
    from /usr/ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/package/tar_reader.rb:55:in `each'
    from /usr/ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/package/tar_input.rb:32:in `initialize'
    from /usr/ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/package/tar_input.rb:17:in `new'
    from /usr/ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/package/tar_input.rb:17:in `open'
    from /usr/ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/package.rb:58:in `open'
    from /usr/ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/format.rb:63:in `from_io'
    from /usr/ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/format.rb:51:in `block in from_file_by_path'
    from /usr/ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/1.9.1/open-uri.rb:35:in `open'
    from /usr/ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/1.9.1/open-uri.rb:35:in `open'
    from /usr/ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/format.rb:50:in `from_file_by_path'
    from /usr/ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.7/lib/bundler/source.rb:72:in `fetch'
    from /usr/ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.7/lib/bundler/installer.rb:45:in `block in run'
    from /usr/ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.7/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:12:in `block in each'
    from /usr/ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.7/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:12:in `each'
    from /usr/ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.7/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:12:in `each'
    from /usr/ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.7/lib/bundler/installer.rb:44:in `run'
    from /usr/ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.7/lib/bundler/installer.rb:8:in `install'
    from /usr/ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.7/lib/bundler/cli.rb:225:in `install'
    from /usr/ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.7/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/task.rb:22:in `run'
    from /usr/ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.7/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/invocation.rb:118:in `invoke_task'
    from /usr/ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.7/lib/bundler/vendor/thor.rb:246:in `dispatch'
    from /usr/ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.7/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/base.rb:389:in `start'
    from /usr/ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.7/bin/bundle:13:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/ruby1.9.2/bin/bundle:19:in `load'
    from /usr/ruby1.9.2/bin/bundle:19:in `<main>'
   FAILED: http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/bundler
```

!     Heroku push rejected, failed to install gems via Bundler

I'm using ruby 1.9.2.

Comment: Could you post output of "bundle install" command?

Answer (score 18):

my workaround is, adding  this to top of Gemfile

```
if RUBY_VERSION =~ /1.9/
    Encoding.default_external = Encoding::UTF_8
    Encoding.default_internal = Encoding::UTF_8
end
```

ref: http://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/178706

Answer (score 1):

According to this similar issue at github on another gem, looks like it is because of lack of declaration of encoding on the gemspec file

https://github.com/RubyMoney/money/pull/87

I checked json 1.5.3 and 1.5.4 source, they both have it.

So, probably another gems next to json, probably don't have that line.

you may want to find out that gems with command `bundle install` in the project root folder.